# How to redirect all URLs that do not have a parameter to another URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wonder how to redirect all URLs in .htaccess that do not have a parameter to another URL.

Example:

Any access without "&tag=xxx" redirects to index.php?tag=xxx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule at top of your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)tag=xxx(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?tag=xxx [L,NC,R=302,QSA]
```

Negative `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` checks whether query parameter is NOT present and `RewriteRule` adds the missing query parameter and does a full redirect.